# Moving average within groups that returns NULL if any row is NULL (Snowflake - SQL)

Tags: sql, window-functions

I need to caluclate the moving average of a column per group (partitioned by `id`). The only twist is that I need the result to be NULL if any value in the corresponding window is NULL.

Example of expected behaviour (for a given `id` and window size=3):

| A | mov_ave_A |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

The first 3 rows of the moving average are NULL, because the first value (which is included in the first 3 windows) is NULL. Row 4 of `mov_ave_A` is equal to 1 because it's the average of rows 2 to 4 of `A`, and so on.

I tried:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN AVG(a) ELSE NULL END
    OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY date_month
    ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS mov_ave_A
```

but I get

> "Sliding window frame unsupported for function CASE".

Also, I'd really like the solution to be short and simple as I need to create 6 such columns. So, I'll have to repeat the logic 6 times.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't perhaps clear. But the mov_ave_A column is my desired output (moving average of A) and A is the input.

Comment: Also, I'm using Snowflake.

Comment: Looks like OVER clause is in the wrong place. Did you try moving “ELSE NULL END” to the end. Should be “AVG() OVER (…) ELSE NULL END”

Comment: Isn't this what `avg` function does? Skip nulls?

Comment: @Stephan But then the inner CASE that I'm using to count NULLs will not have a window. It will count the NULLs in the entire column. I want to count the NULLs per partition.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, but I don't want it to ignore NULLs. AVG only returns NULL if *all* inputs are NULL. I want it to return NULL if *any* of the rows are NULL.

Comment: @Milad the OVER clause is part of the SUM() and AVG() so you need put it right after them, not at the end of your CASE WHEN. See my answer below, you need to have the OVER clause for each AVG and SUM(I replaced SUM with COUNT as it's a better way to check for NULL, but same concept)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your query is the OVER clause is after the END. I believe this should work. You need to have the OVER clause for each window function so once for COUNT and once for AVG. COUNT is a easier to way to check for NULL's then using SUM

```
SELECT 
    *
    ,CASE
        /*Check for 3 values in a, if so return the rolling AVG value. Implicit ELSE NULL*/ 
        WHEN COUNT(a)   OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date_month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) = 3 
        THEN AVG(a)     OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date_month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    END AS mov_ave_A
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following case expression:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(a) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY date_month
    ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) = 3 THEN AVG(a) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY date_month
    ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) END AS mov_avg
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to get NULL for `NULL, 1, 1`.

Comment: The expected result in op says otherwise but anyway, see revised answer.